# Installing weborb for rails - permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, weborb

I'm trying to install weborb for rails on windows xp, rails 2.3.8

I type in my project directory: ruby script plugin install http://themidnightcoders.net:8089/svn/weborb and i get the error:

ruby: Permission denied -- script (Load Error)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, it must have been a long day. I didn't even realize until after posting this and reading it a few times that I left the "/" out from between script and plugin. wow...